# What is another way of saying, "I understood this as saying..."?

Tags: grammar

I need to explain how I interpreted a poem and compare that with another translator's. I'm essentially trying to say something like: "I thought he was saying that _______. The other translation thought he was saying something else." I think I could say "I took this as meaning __________." Is there an alternative that doesn't require "as [meaning/saying/etc] that"?

Comment: My go-to phrase would be "I took this to say..."  You could also say "my interpretation of x was..." or just "my interpretation was..."

Comment: @Some_Guy You could also use "My understanding of x was..."

Comment: I would also go with "interpret". Also something like "to me, this represents / suggests / implies..."

Comment: What's wrong with replacing `took this as meaning` with _intepreted as_? You used _interpreted_ in your question already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I think ... is a plausible alternative to xy's reading of this work."

"On reading this passage, my thoughts were at variance with those of xy's".

Or:

"This except/phrase/etc. is a potential source of ambiguity, in that, unlike xy, it put me in mind of/led me to/left me with the conclusion/impression/etc ..."

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> "I read this as ..."

or

> "My reading of this ..."